# How can I make matplotlib's PolyCollection not interfere with the rendering of lines in a 3d plot?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-3d

PolyCollections seems to render in the foreground of the image, thus making the plot lines obscure. I need to fill the area under the curve in a Joyplot/ridgeline style plot.

I have used the example found in the matplotlibs documentation site to illustrate. The proyect where I was really working on is making a Joy Division style plot for the elevation map of my region. I have already tried using JoyPy but since my data is not aligned I have discarded its use. The way I am making the plot is using matplotlibs 3d plotting since my data is 3-dimensional.

This is a modified version of the example found at: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/polys3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-polys3d-py where I have added the `lines` list.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def polygon_under_graph(x, y):
    """
    Construct the vertex list which defines the polygon filling the space under
    the (x, y) line graph. This assumes x is in ascending order.
    """
    return [(x[0], 0.), *zip(x, y), (x[-1], 0.)]


ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0., 10., 31)
lambdas = range(1, 9)

# verts[i] is a list of (x, y) pairs defining polygon i.
gamma = np.vectorize(math.gamma)
verts = [polygon_under_graph(x, l**x * np.exp(-l) / gamma(x + 1))
         for l in lambdas]
lines = [ax.plot3D(x, np.linspace(l, l, len(x)), l**x * np.exp(-l) / gamma(x + 1), c= "black") for l in lambdas]

facecolors = plt.colormaps['viridis_r'](np.linspace(0, 1, len(verts)))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=facecolors, alpha=0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=lambdas, zdir='y')

ax.set(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(1, 9), zlim=(0, 0.35),
       xlabel='x', ylabel=r'$\lambda$', zlabel='probability')

plt.show()
```

## This is the output:

[image: As you can see, the lines in front seem to be obscured by the polygons on the back]

This is an image of the real proyect I was working on, as you can see, the polyigons in the back dont let you see the lines at the front:[With colorful polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SvD2.png)[No polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ZSe.png)[Black polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaE1B.png)

Comment: did you set the zorders correlctly? (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html)

Comment: @raphael I wasn't aware of this feature, Ill try to mess arround with this. Thank you